# Linq to entities distinct year from datetime column

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a table containing payment records. Those records have a datetime column which contains the actual datetime of the purchase. Now I want to put a dynamically populated dropdown on top of the page so users can select a year and then view the payment records of that year.

In order to do so I try to distinct the years out of the payment records. This is what I have but it fails

```
    List<DateTime> lstYears = new List<DateTime>();
    lstYears = context.Payments
               .Select(
                       p => new { p.TimeOfPurchase.GetValueOrDefault().Year }
                      )
               .Distinct()
               .ToList()
               .Select(x => new DateTime(x.Year, 1, 1))
               .ToList();
```

The error I receive is 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method GetValueOrDefault'. But when I remove that method I cannot type "**p.TimeOfPurchase.Year**".

Is it possible to only select the distinct years of all those payment records?

Comment: Try `p.TimeOfPurchase.Value.Year`.  Since it's translated to SQL the nulls should be handled.

Comment: @juharr that simple change did the trick perfectly, thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `p.TimeOfPurchase.Value.Year`.  Since it's translated to SQL the nulls should be handled.  And you can add a `Where` clause to filter the nulls.  Also you don't need to put it into an anonymous class.  Also you can use `AsEnumerable` to translate to Linq to Objects instead of `ToList` and it will avoid creating an unneeded list.  Finally just assign the query to your variable and don't initialize it with an empty list that just gets thrown away.

```
List<DateTime> lstYears = context.Payments
    .Where(p => p.TimeOfPurchase != null)
    .Select(p => p.TimeOfPurchase.Value.Year)
    .Distinct()
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => new DateTime(x, 1, 1))
    .ToList();
```