# Trying to select distinct list of months from date where year = xxxx - linq to entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm attempting to select a distinct listing of months from a date field where the year = xxxx.  I've read other questions and answers on this site but can't seem to get mine working.  I'm using the entity framework and linq to entities - here is my latest code:

```
 Function BellMonthlySummaryMonthFiltering(years As Nullable(Of Integer), monthval As Nullable(Of Integer)) As JsonResult


        If Not years Is Nothing Then

            Dim listMonths As List(Of DateTime) = db.MobileBill_Summary.Where(Function(o) o.InvoiceDate.Year.Equals(years)).Select(Function(s) s.InvoiceDate.Month).Distinct.AsEnumerable.Select(Function(t) New DateTime(1999, t, 1)).ToList
        End If

        'Return Json(months, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)

    End Function
```

This is the error i get:

Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.  I followed the instructions in this article:

[Linq to entities distinct year from datetime column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35486587/linq-to-entities-distinct-year-from-datetime-column)

Comment: Let's start breaking this query down - i.e. "start deleting crap until it works!".  Would you mind trying before the distinct - after the first select?

Comment: ok i changed the code to this: Dim listMonths As List(Of Integer) = db.MobileBill_Summary.Where(Function(o) o.InvoiceDate.Year.Equals(years)).Select(Function(s) s.InvoiceDate.Month).ToList  and still got the same error

Comment: Ok take off the first select.  You should see where I'm going with this.  It might be your `o.InvoiceDate.Year.Equals(years)`.  Perhaps using the `=` instead might fix it.  This is because it's trying to translate it to SQL.  In the earlier days of LINQ we had built-in helper functions for dates.

Comment: I just noticed years was nullable.... use `years.Value`.  If you want to compare to null as well, use a second comparison operator - `o.InvoiceDate.Year = Nothing Or o.InvoiceDate.Year = years.Value` (sorry if my vb is wrong).

Comment: You're a savior - changing to = worked!  never would have thought.  Final code is: Dim listMonths As List(Of String) = db.MobileBill_Summary.Where(Function(o) o.InvoiceDate.Year = years).Select(Function(s) s.InvoiceDate.Month).Distinct.AsEnumerable.Select(Function(t) New String(MonthName(t))).ToList   - to get a list of month names

Comment: Glad you got it!  Added my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your where clause to this:

```
Where(Function(o) o.InvoiceDate.Year = years)
```

This is due to how EF does its conversion to SQL.